# Why does file_get_contents() return the error "Filename cannot be empty"?

Tags: php

I'm pretty much a complete newbie to PHP. My background is C/C++ and C#. I'm trying to object orient-ify some simple PHP code, but I'm doing something wrong.

Class code:

```
class ConnectionString
{
  public $String = "";
  public $HostName = "";
  public $UserName = "";
  public $Password = "";
  public $Database = "";

  function LoadFromFile($FileName)
  {
    $this->String = file_get_contents($Filename);
    $Values = explode("|", $this->String);
    $this->HostName = $Values[0];
    $this->UserName = $Values[1];
    $this->Password = $Values[2];
    $this->Database = $Values[3];
  }
}
```

Calling code:

```
$ConnectionString = new ConnectionString();
$FileName = "db.conf";
$ConnectionString->LoadFromFile($FileName);
print('<p>Connection Info: ' . $Connection->String . '</p>');
```

I'm getting ann error on the `file_get_contents($Filename)` line stating: *Filename cannot be empty*.  If I hard-code the filename in place of $Filename, then I simply get all empty strings for the fields.

What simple concept am I missing?

Comment: This may be the best written question with the word "newbie" in the title, ever.  +1.

Comment: No surprise here as he's coming from a C/C++ background.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You've got the case wrong:

```
file_get_contents($Filename);
```

should be

```
file_get_contents($FileName);
```

You should turn on Notices, either in your php.ini file or using [error_reporting()](http://php.net/error_reporting)

Comment: Gotta love dynamic languages here.

Comment: Wow. I knew it was something stupid. Thanks (everyone) for the help. I actually didn't realize that PHP was case sensitive. I'm lucky I've gotten this far. 

@Greg, thanks for the tip on NOtices and error_reporting(). I wasn't aware of them.

Answer (score 3):

Variables in PHP are case-sensitive. You've defined `$FileName` as a parameter to the `LoadFromFile()` method, but you used `$Filename` on the first line of that method. For more information about PHP variables:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

There are a few things you can do to avoid this problem in the future:

- Use an IDE, such as [Eclipse PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/), that support auto-completion of variables.
- Configure [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to display all types of errors (`E_ALL`).

Answer (score 1):

Variable case-sensitivity:

```
function LoadFromFile($FileName)
{
   $this->String = file_get_contents($Filename); // This should be $FileName!
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->String = file_get_contents($FileName);
```

you have `$Filename`

Answer (score 1):

```
 $this->String = file_get_contents($Filename);
```

On this line, you write $File**n**ame when it should be $File**N**ame